# delete item in list

Tags: development, sharepoint-designer

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
    SPList list = web.Lists["MyList"];
    if (list != null)
    {
        for (int i = list.ItemCount - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            list.Items[i].Delete();
        }
        list.Update();
    }
```

I have more Items in an SharePoint list then when i in an listbox select only one item and delete if with the following code , then it deletes al the items in my list , not just the only I have selected , can somebody help me ?

Comment: Okay, post the code which you used to bind listitems with listbox pls!

Answer (score 2):

This is an alternative to Jussi Palo's answer, but without iterating through ALL the list items, which is a huge performance loss.

```
string filtervalue = TextBox1.Text; // Value you selected, criteria for deletion.
SPWeb currentWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPList list = currentWeb.Lists.TryGetList("MyList");
if(list==null)
    throw new InvalidOperationException("MyList does not exist on current site.");
SPQuery query = new SPQuery()
{
    Query = string.Format("<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='MyField' /><Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value></Eq></Where>", filtervalue),
    ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='ID' />",
    ViewFieldsOnly = true
};
SPListItemCollection filteredItems = list.GetItems(query);

foreach (SPListItem item in filteredItems)
{
    item.Delete();
    break; // If you want to delete ONLY the first occurence.
}
list.Update();
```

Also, if by any chance you know the ID of the item you selected, you can pass that as a parameter to the following method:

```
list.Items.DeleteItemById(SelectedId);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are deleting all items. You need to have some check within the for loop to only delete the item you want.

Example:

```
SPWeb mySite = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPListItemCollection listItems = mySite.Lists.TryGetList("listname").Items;
int itemCount = listItems.Count;

for (int k=0; k<itemCount; k++)
{
    SPListItem item = listItems[k];

    if (TextBox2.Text==item["Employee"].ToString())
    {
        listItems.Delete(k);
        break; // Only break away if you want to delete one item ONLY!
    }
}
```

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms467435%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: by all means, avoid doing mySite.Lists[TextBox1.Text], it loads all the lists belonging to the site and just to get one.
Instead, you can use mySite.Lists.TryGetList(listName)

Comment: Thanks Jaime, one should never assume MSDN code is optimal :)